# What do they want me prove?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm having trouble understanding what they actually want me to prove.
Here is the question:

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph. Recall that the degree of a vertex
$v \in V$ , denoted $d_v$, is the number of vertices $w$ such that there is an edge between $v$ and $w$.

(a) [10 pts] Prove that

$$2|E| = \sum_{v \in V} d_v.$$

Could anyone tell me in words what this formula means?
See the question in it's original source (it is listed as 2a) at:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_042JF10_assn04.pdf

I don't want any solution, I'm just not understanding the formula.

Comment: $\Sigma$ means sum. Google "summation notation."

Comment: You are being asked to prove that twice the number of edges in a graph is equal to the sum of the degrees of each of its vertices.

Comment: See the [handshake lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma)

Answer (score 3):

The problem on the link you furnished is to show $$2|E| = \sum_{v\in V}d_v$$ The symbol on the right means the sum of the degrees of all of the vertices in the vertex set. The symbol on the left is twice the size of the edge set (i.e., twice the number of edges).